# Zip code with dash

Tags: android, validation, android-layout, zipcode

It is possible in android `EditText` to write zip code with dash (for example '55-555'). Only one dash in the middle. I mean I want to add dash ("-") to the numeric keyboard.

Comment: `android:digits="0123456789-"`

Comment: But can I programme this? I mean I want only one dash in the middle of digits...

Comment: do you need to insert the dash at a fixed position i.e. the dash is always inserted at index 2?

Comment: Yes and no. I need to insert only one dash in edittext (in the middle of digits). I don't know that it can be only on index 2...

Comment: I other words: It is possible to validate `EditText` live - when typing text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `TextWatcher` to insert a dash when a user is typing the zip code. The following example is inserting a dash character at index 2.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().contains("-") && s.length() > 2) {
                s.insert(2, "-");
            }

        }
});
```